# For the Divination wizard's Portent feature, how do "glimpses of the future" manifest?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, divination

The [Divination wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/wizard#SchoolofDivination)'s Portent feature description (PHB, p. 116) begins:

> Starting at 2nd level when you choose this school, glimpses of the future begin to press in on your awareness.

Most of the discussion online seems to be about the dice roll mechanics of Portent.

What are the implications of "glimpses of the future begin to press in on your awareness" in terms of non-combat storytelling?

Also, how does this change at level 14 (when the wizard gets a 3rd Portent die)?

It seems like there's a lot of potential to provide some tantalising hints of the future, yet at the same time creates significant challenges due to player agency (not that an adventuring party has upset the carefully laid plans of a DM, ever).

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It's up to your table.

D&D 5E follows this structure often in defining abilities, spells, and so on. It will lead with one sentence of fluff, followed by all the mechanics, and Portent is no different.

As such, what you're asking for doesn't have a hard-and-fast answer the way that the mechanics do. And that's okay, because it means that you get to fill in those details on your own. Anything from straight up ignoring it in favor of the mechanics, to using it to deliver hints of the upcoming plot and even plot hooks like you suggest, is valid, so long as it works for your table.

And that is just down to a conversation with everyone else at your table.

Comment: While I appreciate the acceptance, this answer has been up for only six hours. You'll get a better choice of answers if you let the question sit for at least 24 hours so people in other time zones can answer as well.